# .htaccess Internal Server Error on ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

i had an error on .htaccess here

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    rewriterule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    rewriterule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
<ifmodule>
```

and the directory 'webroot' contains .htaccess file

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L]
</ifmodule>
```

what is the wrong on .htaccess file

i tried alot of solutions and does not work

iam new to php mvc and i want to make webroot the root directory

Comment: any php developer deal with mvc can help ...thanks tags has been edited to more specific tags

Comment: Why the PT parameter ? Did you tried to remove it?

Comment: For sure you missed a </ifmodule> closure in the firs code snippet...

Comment: what happened in apache error.log ?

Comment: the error has been disappered but it doesnot redirect to webroot folder